# are all 18650 batteries interchangeable with one another?

Tags: batteries

I recently bought a [PowerTac E9R-G4](https://www.powertac.com/Item/E9R-G4) flashlight that uses 18650 batteries. Replacements can be bought on amazon.com fairly cheaply.

The box the flashlight comes in and the manual, however, both say "*ONLY USE PowerTac 18650-3200mAh High Drain batteries*".

The battery that the flashlight came with says "*11A max continuous discharge - 15A max pulse discharge*". Maybe regular 18650 batteries don't support pulse discharges at that amperage? Altho then again idk why pulse discharge would matter unless I was using the strobe mode that the flashlight has?

What would / could happen if I used other 18650 batteries? More generally, are all 18650 batteries interchangeable with one another?

Comment: 18650 is a battery form factor, not a battery chemistry. So no, not all 18650 batteries are interchangeable.

Comment: The specs stated are for the battery and MAY be true - but do not indicate what the light needs - they are just what the battery is nominally capable of. Max power is 2550 lumen for 2 hours. That SHOULD be under 3 Watts so 6 Watt hours. The battery is nominally 3.6V x 3.2 Ah = 11.5 Watt-hour or 5.7W x 2 hours. So the light is less efficient than expected or brighter or the battery is lower energy content than claimed. 3.2 Ah/2 hours = 1.6A = within the capability of almost any 18650 cell.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon 2550 lumen with that LED is over 3A@6V so over 18W probably.  Neubert, typically the turbo mode has thermal limiting so the LED comes on at high brightness and maximum current and dims as it heats up from both loss of efficiency and current limiting.  18650 cells with higher current ratings usually have lower capacity to match.  Only a relatively few high end companies are really accurate about the mAh ratings of their cells, so if you're buying cells online I wouldn't expect complete garbage, but I wouldn't expect them to live up to their numbers. A datasheet is a good sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though they are not interchangeable, most likely you could use a wide variety of 18650 batteries with that light. The manual is BS as far as I am concerned. I notice that the spec sheet says even in turbo mode the 3.2 Ah battery will last for over 2 hours. This means it is actually not a high discharge application. The cell is only running at 0.5C or less.

So you can use any quality 18650 cell. Unfortunately there are a lot of junky cells out there so buyer beware. For sure anything that claims more than around 3.5 Ah is fake or junky.

I would suggest getting a protected cell rather than a raw/bare cell.

Comment: This answer is good but ignores charging current : if it discharges at C/2 but charges in 15 minutes (4C) then the specified cell would be more important.